# Nuxeo ldap direct manager username mapping

Tags: java, xml, ldap, nuxeo

I'm using Nuxeo platform for my company and we've got an LDAP server that contains a lot of details about every employee, one of the attributes is the "direct manager" for the employee, the attribute's value is returned in this format:

```
"uid=<username>,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=<Some_Domain_Component>,dc=<Some_Domain_Component>"
```

**What I'm trying to do is to extract only the "username" from the value above and map it to a custom field in Nuxeo**. Till now I made a custom field and did the mapping for the whole value but I couldn't get only the username from it.

Any ideas? btw, I've tried to post this question in [answers.nuxeo.com](https://answers.nuxeo.com/) but when I register, my account is not being approved and I don't know why.

Comment: maybe this link can help you  https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/using-a-ldap-directory/

Comment: @Saimir nothing useful